# Entity Group Consitency after PUT in Appengine HRD

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, entity-groups

Say I have an Entity A and an Entity B, A is a parent of B, that is, many B's can be part of a single A's entity group.

Now, say I put to the HRD a bunch of B's (across many entity groups - i.e. they across many A parents). If I now query for all B's within a single entity group (i.e. the same A parent), am I guaranteed strong consistency? The subtlety here is that although I'm querying over a single entity group the orignal PUT was over multiple entity groups.

Comment: You might need to give an example of the (ancestor?) query that you would like do, against which entities A? B?, and which entities you want to ensure are up to date in the returned results. This will make it easier to answer.

Comment: I would be querying for B's. I.e. give me all B's who have a particular A as a parent. Are all the B's in this query strongly consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - queries over a single entity group (provided you specified an ancestor filter - simply having all the results coincidentally in the same group is not sufficient) are always strongly consistent.